# Find link in text and replace with "a" tag

Tags: beautifulsoup, replace, findall

I have a partially good HTML, I need to create hyperlink, like:

> Superotto: risorse audiovisive per superare i pregiudizi e celebrare
> l’otto marzo, in “Indire Informa”, 5 marzo 2021,
> https://www.indire.it/2021/03/05/superotto-risorse-audiovisive-per-superare-i-pregiudizi-e-celebrare-lotto-marzo/;
> Sezione Superotto in
> https://piccolescuole.indire.it/iniziative/la-scuola-allo-schermo/#superotto.

Has to become:

> Superotto: risorse audiovisive per superare i pregiudizi e celebrare
> l’otto marzo, in “Indire Informa”, 5 marzo 2021, < a
> href="https://www.indire.it/2021/03/05/superotto-risorse-audiovisive-per-superare-i-pregiudizi-e-celebrare-lotto-marzo/" >https://www.indire.it/2021/03/05/superotto-risorse-audiovisive-per-superare-i-pregiudizi-e-celebrare-lotto-marzo/< /a >;
> Sezione Superotto in < a
> href="https://piccolescuole.indire.it/iniziative/la-scuola-allo-schermo/#superotto">https://piccolescuole.indire.it/iniziative/la-scuola-allo-schermo/#superotto< /a >.

Beautifulsoup seems to not find the http well, so I used this regex with the pure python findall, but I cannot substitute or compose the text. Right now I made:

```
links = re.findall(r"(http|ftp|https:\/\/)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])", str(soup))
    link_to_replace = []
    for l in links:
        link = ''.join(l)
        if link in soup.find("body").text:
            good_link = "<a href="+link+">"+link+"</a>"
            fixed_text = soup.replace(link, good_link)
            soup.replace_with(fixed_text)
```

I tried multiple solutions in the last two lines (this is just one), none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as follows, where I first identify the relevant anchor elements and strip out any other attributes besides the href, then later substitute the href link with the href html

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://rivista.clionet.it/vol5/giorgi-zoppi-la-ricerca-indire-tra-uso-didattico-del-patrimonio-storico-culturale-e-promozione-delle-buone-pratiche/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
item = soup.select_one('p:has(a[id="ft-note-16"])')
text = item.text

for tag in item.select('a:not([id])'):
    href = tag['href']
    tag.attrs = {'href': href}
    text = re.sub(href, str(tag), text)

text = re.sub(item.a.text, '', text).strip()
print(text)
```